# graylog 4.0 - Injector could not be created

Tags: ansible, mongodb, elasticsearch, graylog

Trying to set up graylog with official [graylog2.graylog ansible role](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-ansible-role).

Installed Elasticsearch (v7.10.2) cluster on three separate servers with official elasticsearch ansible role (node_1 - master, node_2 and node_3 - data) - no problems so far.

When running graylog ansible (against another server) all is successful (including installation of MongoDB on the same graylog host), but restart of graylog-server systemd unit is unsuccessful and as a result ansible play fails (which is expected).

The content of **/var/log/graylog-server/server.log**:

```
2021-10-23T15:13:39.037+03:00 INFO  [CmdLineTool] Running with JVM arguments: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms1500m -Xmx1500m -XX:NewRatio=1 -XX:+ResizeTLAB -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:///etc/graylog/server/log4j2.xml -Djava.library.path=/usr/share/graylog-server/lib/sigar -Dgraylog2.installation_source=deb
2021-10-23T15:13:39.212+03:00 INFO  [Version] HV000001: Hibernate Validator null
2021-10-23T15:13:39.760+03:00 ERROR [CmdLineTool] Injector creation failed!
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2051) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3951) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3974) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4958) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.getUnchecked(LocalCache.java:4964) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache.get(FailableCache.java:51) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.get(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:48) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.initialize(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:155) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:581) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractBindingProcessor$Processor$1.run(AbstractBindingProcessor.java:176) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProcessedBindingData.initializeBindings(ProcessedBindingData.java:49) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:122) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.shared.bindings.GuiceInjectorHolder.createInjector(GuiceInjectorHolder.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool.setupInjector(CmdLineTool.java:381) [graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.bootstrap.CmdLineTool.run(CmdLineTool.java:196) [graylog.jar:?]
    at org.graylog2.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:50) [graylog.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @10315254
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:336) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:157) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:149) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:145) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$MethodWrapper.<clinit>(MethodWrapper.java:23) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DuplicatesPredicate.evaluate(DuplicatesPredicate.java:104) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$CollectionUtils.filter(CollectionUtils.java:52) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:69) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @10315254
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClassEmitter.<init>(FastClassEmitter.java:67) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.generateClass(FastClass.java:77) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.internal.$LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.core.$AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastClass$Generator.create(FastClass.java:65) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:258) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.BytecodeGen.newFastClassForMember(BytecodeGen.java:207) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.create(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:49) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:156) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.createConstructor(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:92) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore.access$000(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:29) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:37) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjectorStore$1.create(ConstructorInjectorStore.java:33) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.inject.internal.FailableCache$1.load(FailableCache.java:40) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3529) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2278) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2155) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2045) ~[graylog.jar:?]
    ... 17 more
2021-10-23T15:13:39.764+03:00 ERROR [CmdLineTool] Injector could not be created, exiting! (Please include the previous error messages in bug reports.)
```

The content of **/etc/graylog/server/server.conf** (comments removed):

```
is_master = True
node_id_file = /etc/graylog/server/node-id
password_secret = RPGAmtkheVukBFhSANMoY0L9FEzYTTVhWzPDmhCVFW9l26IG2Hn5FXtZ2lkWwKAKos5Pz9bDDb5mLtnWf3Cpbyux9xZNEzPt
root_username = admin
root_password_sha2 = 698f4900fa6a5ef2c6044b56ab789503e432a420e5a9ha93d0f98dd8510bdeco
root_email =
root_timezone = UTC
bin_dir = /usr/share/graylog-server/bin
data_dir = /graylog_data/graylog
plugin_dir = /usr/share/graylog-server/plugin
http_bind_address = 0.0.0.0:9000
http_publish_uri = http://10.176.35.94:9000/
http_external_uri = http://10.176.35.100:9000/
http_enable_cors = True
http_enable_gzip = True
http_max_header_size = 8192
http_thread_pool_size = 16
http_enable_tls = False
elasticsearch_hosts = http://10.176.35.91:9200,http://10.176.35.92:9200,http://10.176.35.93:9200,
elasticsearch_socket_timeout = 60s
elasticsearch_max_total_connections = 20
elasticsearch_max_total_connections_per_route = 2
elasticsearch_max_retries = 2
elasticsearch_discovery_enabled = False
elasticsearch_discovery_frequency = 30s
elasticsearch_compression_enabled = False
rotation_strategy = count
elasticsearch_max_docs_per_index = 20000000
elasticsearch_max_size_per_index = 1073741824
elasticsearch_max_time_per_index = 1d
elasticsearch_disable_version_check = True
no_retention = False
elasticsearch_max_number_of_indices = 20
retention_strategy = delete
elasticsearch_shards = 4
elasticsearch_replicas = 0
elasticsearch_index_prefix = graylog
elasticsearch_template_name = graylog-internal
allow_leading_wildcard_searches = False
allow_highlighting = False
elasticsearch_analyzer = standard
elasticsearch_request_timeout = 1m
elasticsearch_index_optimization_timeout = 1h
elasticsearch_index_optimization_jobs = 20
index_ranges_cleanup_interval = 1h
index_field_type_periodical_interval = 1h
output_batch_size = 500
output_flush_interval = 1
output_fault_count_threshold = 5
output_fault_penalty_seconds = 30
processbuffer_processors = 5
outputbuffer_processors = 3
outputbuffer_processor_keep_alive_time = 5000
outputbuffer_processor_threads_core_pool_size = 3
outputbuffer_processor_threads_max_pool_size = 30
udp_recvbuffer_sizes = 1048576
processor_wait_strategy = blocking
ring_size = 65536
inputbuffer_ring_size = 65536
inputbuffer_processors = 2
inputbuffer_wait_strategy = blocking
message_journal_enabled = True
message_journal_dir = /var/lib/graylog-server/journal
message_journal_max_age = 12h
message_journal_max_size = 5gb
message_journal_flush_age = 1m
message_journal_flush_interval = 1000000
message_journal_segment_age = 1h
message_journal_segment_size = 100mb
async_eventbus_processors = 2
lb_recognition_period_seconds = 3
lb_throttle_threshold_percentage = 95
stream_processing_timeout = 2000
stream_processing_max_faults = 3
alert_check_interval = 60
output_module_timeout = 10000
stale_master_timeout = 2000
shutdown_timeout = 30000
mongodb_uri = mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/graylog
mongodb_max_connections = 100
mongodb_threads_allowed_to_block_multiplier = 5
transport_email_enabled = False
transport_email_hostname =
transport_email_port = 587
transport_email_use_auth = True
transport_email_auth_username =
transport_email_auth_password =
transport_email_subject_prefix = [graylog]
transport_email_from_email =
transport_email_use_tls = True
transport_email_web_interface_url =
http_connect_timeout = 5s
http_read_timeout = 10s
http_write_timeout = 10s
disable_index_optimization = True
index_optimization_max_num_segments = 1
gc_warning_threshold = 1s
ldap_connection_timeout = 2000
disable_sigar = False
dashboard_widget_default_cache_time = 10s
proxied_requests_thread_pool_size = 32
```

Please let me know how could I fix this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by checking and installing correct Java version with `lean_delivery.java` ansible role (var `java_major_version: 8`)